# How to insert QR Code in CV

Tags: xetex, friggeri-cv, qrcode

Given [this](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv) CV/Resume template in `xelatex` (see picture below), how can I add an image above "contact" and a QR Code to the side panel under the category "programming"?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use include graphics for example:

```
\begin{aside} % In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\includegraphics{qr_code}

\section{contact}
```

I have not tested yet but perhaps you'll need to add `\usepackage{graphicx}`.

The `aside` environnement create the part with contact, languages and programming. So If you add a picture in the code before the section contact you'll have your qrcode.